# How can I move back to old intellij idea UI?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've got [a new Intellij Idea UI](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2022/05/take-part-in-the-new-ui-preview-for-your-jetbrains-ide/) (I applied for testing) but I want to move back to the old one and can't find a way to do that.
How can I disable a new UI?

Version: 2022.2.1

Comment: Perhaps if you were kind enough to specify which version(s) of intellij you're using people may be able to help you (assuming there's something to do here).

Comment: Thanks @MartinMarconcini
I've added information about version.

Comment: I think you also need to add the information about which version you had before, because reading the [changelog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2022/08/intellij-idea-2022-2-1/) for that new version, it's a _minor_ update that doesn't mention a new UI.

Comment: `Help | Find Action, Registry`, start typing the key name for `ide.experimental.ui`, then disable it. Restart the IDE.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

In 2022.3 IDE version new UI can be enabled/disabled without modifying registry keys.

`Settings | Appearance & Behavior | New UI`:

[image]

**Original Answer:**

Go to `Help | Find Action | Registry`, start typing the key name for `ide.experimental.ui`, then disable it. Restart the IDE.

Comment: I just hate this new UI. I hope they do not remove the old.

Answer (score 3):

Open Settings with CTRL + ALT + S and look for 'Appeareance & Behavior -> New UI'

You can also access the Settings by clicking on the icon in the top right.